# "system is computationally singular" error when I use 'winsorize'

Tags: r, syntax-error, singular

I am going to `winsorize` my dataset to get rid of some outliers with the package `robustHD`. It is the first time I ran into this error. The dataset contains 50+ variables and 100+ observations.

How can I fix this? And why matrix singularity matters for a calculation like `winsorize`? Thanks.

```
df_win<-winsorize(df,prob=0.95)
Error in solve.default(R) : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.26103e-18
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. It would be really helpful if the example was reproducible. Could you provide a minimal dataset that replicates this error? Could you also note from which package you got the `winsorize` function? Multiple packages provide one.

Comment: @Laterow Thanks! I used the package 'robustHD'. Sorry I can't upload the data since it's related to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that `winsorize` in `robustHD` uses `solve`. If you look deeper into the code, `winsorize` on a data frame calls the `winsorize.data.frame` method, which is simply a script that runs `as.matrix` and then uses the `winsorize.matrix` method. This in turns does a bunch of things, but the problem here is that it uses the `solve` function.

The error you get is from `solve`. The error probably occurs because you included some variables/columns that are very highly correlated, or rather, they are linear combinations of each other. You may want to check if you have duplicated variables or variables that are transformations of each other.

There are several things you can do:

1. Remove one of the highly correlated variables and try again.
2. Check out a different package to use `winsorize` from.
3. Write your own winsorize function.

The quickest way to do the second step:

```
require(sos)
findFn("winsorize")
```

This will produce an overview of all functions that have the word "winsorize" in their description. Just look for functions that are described to be used for winsorization.

Comment: Thanks @Laterow. Okay I got it. The findFn is very useful too. Thanks a lot!